# Problems when Slicing the Tensor in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I met some problems in slicing the tensor by defining a function named `slice()` in Keras.

The target of this function is slicing the tensor from `(1, 512, 512, 1)` to `(1, 495, 383, 1)`.

Therefore, I defined a function as follows:

```py
def slice(x, n, h1, h2, w1, w2, d):
  return x[n, h1:h2, w1:w2, d]
```

Then, I called the function with the following instructions:

```py
x = Lambda(slice, arguments={'n':1, 'h1': 0, 'h2': 495, 'w1': 0, 'w2': 383, 'd':1})(x)
```

However, after calling the function, the shape became `(1, None, 383, 1)`, but not `(1, 495, 383, 1)`.

Could you give me some explanations and solutions to this error? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `n` and `d` be 0 if the shape is (1, x, y, 1)? I try this code out on Keras 2.4.3 and it works as expected - [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tS27ECcUdrqr68w0o3KrIYXMFwdTwCoL?usp=sharing)

Comment: Dear Andrew: Thanks for your response. I have tried to apply your code, however, the dim finally became `(495, 383)`, but not `(1, 495, 383, 1)`. I have tried to use `np.expand_dim()` or colon operator, but it doesn't work. Could you please tell me the method to expand the dim from `(495, 383)` to `(1, 495, 383, 1)`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I need to reply here since I can't add my suggestion to the comments yet. If you need to expand the dimensions from (495, 383) to (1, 495, 383, 1) you might want to simply redefine your *slice* function as:

```
def slice(x, n, h1, h2, w1, w2, d):
   return tf.reshape(x[n, h1:h2, w1:w2, d], shape=(1, h2-h1, w2-w1, 1))
```

Comment: Dear Massimo: Thanks for your response, and it works! Have a nice day :)